# Converting code using AsyncTask to use Executor Service

Tags: java, android-asynctask, android-room, executorservice, executor

I am having below code that uses AsyncTask to do some task in background but i would like to migrate to ExecutorService, the problem i am having is that my AsyncTask class has a constructor

Below is my AsyncTask method

```
private static class UpdateCustomerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Customer, Void, Void>{

        private CustomerDao customerDao;

        public UpdateCustomerAsyncTask(CustomerDao customerDao) {
            this.customerDao = customerDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Customer... customers) {

            try{

                customerDao.updateCustomer(customers[0]);

            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The above class is supposed to do the task of updating room database in background

I know how use Executor Service in a simple way but i would like some help when using the ExecutorService with a class which extends the Executor Service like the above way where i have extended AsyncTask

Below is how i tried implementing using Simple Executor Service but i am stuck when extending the Executor Service with a class

```
int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
executorService.execute(() -> {

     customerDao.updateCustomer(customers[0]);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

For Executors i think below class is solve your problem and really help full while working with `room`. Check below

```
public class AppExecutors {

    private final Executor mDiskIO;

    private final Executor mNetworkIO;

    private final Executor mMainThread;

    private AppExecutors(Executor diskIO, Executor networkIO, Executor mainThread) {
        this.mDiskIO = diskIO;
        this.mNetworkIO = networkIO;
        this.mMainThread = mainThread;
    }

    public AppExecutors() {
        this(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3),
                new MainThreadExecutor());
    }

    public Executor diskIO() {
        return mDiskIO;
    }

    public Executor networkIO() {
        return mNetworkIO;
    }

    public Executor mainThread() {
        return mMainThread;
    }

    private static class MainThreadExecutor implements Executor {
        private Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        @Override
        public void execute(@NonNull Runnable command) {
            mainThreadHandler.post(command);
        }
    }
}
```

And to update your custom use like this.

```
    void updateCustomer(Integer id, Activity context){
            YourDatabase database =  YourDatabase.getDatabase(context)
AppExecutors appExecutors =  new AppExecutors();
        appExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             database.customerDao.updateCustomer(customers[id]);
            }
        });
            
   }
```

Comment: do have this code in java i don't speak kotlin

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo check java version.

Comment: do you have a link

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo Here's link of jetpack component usage AppExecutors you can see it if you know about android jetpack.  https://github.com/AweiLoveAndroid/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample

Comment: Thanks @Anas Mehar for the java version